# Soundproofing external HVAC

Tags: hvac, sound-proofing

I am looking to build a fence around my outside air conditioning unit to reduce the decibels for the neighbors. Is there any tips on how to construct such unit? Are there any ready to use commercial solutions that I can try ? (Except for using soundblanket that i have already put on)

Comment: Any reduction in air flow will affect your systems efficiency and may reduce the life of the system a baffled approach is best but even that can affect airflow and reduce efficiency.

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m8P1V3h0aaY

Comment: Why aren't the neighbors trying to solve their problem? Do you have a regular AC unit?

Comment: What @MonkeyZeus wrote. Take that blanket off immediately!

Comment: Mine is a regular ac unit. Sound decibels are like 60 with the blanket which is great for the unit. However, neighbor is saying that my sound is higher than the city's limits.

Comment: how do the neighbors know this?

Comment: It's on the internet and you have apps that can tell you the decibels.

Comment: A lot of folks I know build some kind of fence around their AC unit for both looks and sound attenuation: see e.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=fence+around+AC+unit

Comment: Wow 60 db is not that loud, unless they have a class A sound meter they don’t know. That was considered very quiet for a printer until Hp came out with inkjet . 60db is about conversational level. Do you know the difference in 60 and 63 is double the sound or 60 and 57 is 1/2 the sound the human ear is the worst for evaluating sound volume. Don’t put anything directly on your unit it will bake the compressor and if the temps get high enough it will start shutting down your system along with raising your power bill.

Comment: I agree. Unfortunately the city's sound limits are pretty archaic. So I'm in a bind ok what to do.

Answer (score 3):

Shrubbery placed a reasonable distance from the Condenser works fairly well and looks good. If it shades the AC even the better.

Comment: This works very well. Noise is reduced not only by absorption when sound travels through the leaves to the neighbours, but also when it reflects off surrounding house walls.  Even a wall climbing plant will reduce the noise as it absorbs reflections. You won't get it silent, but the irritating higher pitched whining or humming well be less.